# При парсинге json объект превращается в map

Tags: json, парсер, golang, кодировка, json-rpc

У меня есть 2 структуры

```go
type Input struct {
    Nonce  uint64 `json:"nonce"`
    Key    string `json:"key"`
    Object interface{} `json:"object"`
}

type UserRegister struct {
    Login string `json:"login"`
    Pass  string `json:"pass"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    IsAdmin int  `json:"is_admin,omitempty"`
}
```

И такой кусочек кода

```go
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
if err != nil {
    json.NewEncoder(writer).Encode(serverError)
    log.Print(serverError, err)
    return
}
input := obj.Input{
    Nonce: 0,
    Key: "k",
    Object: obj.UserRegister{
        Login: "l",
        Pass: "p",
        Name: "n",
        Email: "e",
        IsAdmin: 0,
    },
}
json.NewEncoder(writer).Encode(input)
log.Print("empty input: ", input)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &input)
if err != nil {
    json.NewEncoder(writer).Encode(serverError)
    log.Print(serverError, err)
    return
}
log.Print(input)
```

Я передаю POST запросом json

```json
{"nonce":6845,"key":"key","object":{"login":"login","pass":"pass","name":"name","email":"email","is_admin":2}
```

Но после парсинга объект "чудесным" образом превращается в мапу. Логи:

empty input: {0 k {l p n e 0}}

{6845 key map[email:email is_admin:2 login:login pass:pass name:name]}

Как решить эту проблему?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ну дык у вас Object типа `interface{}`. Сделайте его UserRegister'ом и будет нормально.

Comment: это сделано с целью того чтобы можно было запихать любой объект, и в input это UserRegister. Я нашел ответ на то как исправить эту проблему с map[]. [example](https://play.golang.org/p/GXn9pL4xAp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш настоящий вопрос о том, как декодировать объекты разного типа. Делается это всегда в два этапа: сначала декодируете верхний уровень, в котором находится идентификатор типа объекта, а потом уже сам объект. Это можно делать либо в методе `UnmarshalJSON`, либо на стороне клиента. Вариант с клиентом:

```
type Input struct {
    Nonce  uint64          `json:"nonce"`
    Key    string          `json:"key"`
    Object json.RawMessage `json:"object"`
}

// ...

input := Input{}
err := json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&input)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ur := UserRegister{}
err = json.Unmarshal(input.Object, &ur)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xwjsFNsgP_.

Comment: Вах, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

[Решение того как конвертировать map в Object](https://play.golang.org/p/GXn9pL4xAp)

```go
func SetField(obj interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)

    if !structFieldValue.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("No such field: %s in obj", name)
    }

    if !structFieldValue.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot set %s field value", name)
    }

    structFieldType := structFieldValue.Type()
    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if structFieldType != val.Type() {
        invalidTypeError := errors.New("Provided value type didn't match obj field type")
        return invalidTypeError
    }

    structFieldValue.Set(val)
    return nil
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}

func (s *MyStruct) FillStruct(m map[string]interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range m {
        err := SetField(s, k, v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    myData := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["Name"] = "Tony"
    myData["Age"] = int64(23)

    fmt.Println(myData)
    result := MyStruct{}
    err := result.FillStruct(myData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/205598)

Comment: @Komdosh Благодарю, исправил